# Understanding cyclic polynomial hash collisions

Tags: hash, n-gram, hash-collision

I have a code that uses a cyclic polynomial rolling hash (Buzhash) to compute hash values of n-grams of source code. If i use small hash values (7-8 bits) then there are some collisions i.e. different n-grams map to the same hash value. If i increase the bits in the hash value to say 31, then there are 0 collisions - all ngrams map to different hash values.

I want to know why this is so? Do the collisions depend on the number of n-grams in the text or the number of different characters that an n-gram can have or is it the size of an n-gram?

How does one choose the number of bits for the hash value when hashing n-grams (using rolling hashes)?

Comment: At the risk of betraying my total ignorance... aren't smaller hash values always more likely to collide?  (Everything else being equal (so to speak), meaning, same algorithm.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**How Length effects Collisions**

This is simply a question of permutations.

> If i use small hash values (7-8 bits) then there are some collisions

Well, let's analyse this. With 8 bits, there are `2^8` possible binary sequences that can be generated for any given input. That is 256 possible hash values that can be generated, which means that in theory, every `256` message digest values generated guarantee a collision. This is called the birthday problem.

> If i increase the bits in the hash value to say 31, then there are 0 collisions - all ngrams map to different hash values.

Well, let's apply the same logic. With 31 bit precision, we have `2^31` possible combinations. That is `2147483648` possible combinations. And we can generalise this to:

```
Let N denote the amount of bits we use.
Amount of different hash values we can generate (X) = 2^N

Assuming repetition of values is allowed (which it is in this case!)
```

This is an exponential growth, which is why with 8 bits, you found a lot of collisions and with 31 bits, you've found very little collisions.

*How does this effect collisions?*

Well, with a very small amount of values, and an equal chance for each of those values being mapped to an input, you have it that:

```
Let A denote the number of different values already generated.
Chance of a collision is: A / X 

Where X is the possible number of outputs the hashing algorithm can generate.
```

When `X` equals `256`, you have a `1/256` chance of a collision, the first time around. Then you have a `2/256` chance of a collision when a different value is generated. Until eventually, you have generated 255 different values and you have a `255/256` chance of a collision. The next time around, obviously it becomes a `256/256` chance, or `1`, which is a probabilistic certainty. Obviously it usually won't reach this point. A collision will likely occur a lot more than every `256` cycles. In fact, the Birthday paradox tells us that we can start to expect a collision after `2^N/2` message digest values have been generated. So following our example, that's after we've created `16` unique hashes. We do know, however, that it has to happen, *at minimum*, every `256` cycles. Which isn't good!

What this means, on a mathematical level, is that the chance of a collision is *inversely proportional* to the possible number of outputs, which is why we need to increase the size of our message digest to a reasonable length.

**A note on hashing algorithms**

Collisions are completely unavoidable. This is because, there are an extremely large number of possible inputs (2^All possible character codes), and a finite number of possible outputs (as demonstrated above).

Comment: Nitpicking: the number of possible inputs can be very large, but it is not infinite.

Comment: Fair point, it's limited by the number of possible character codes we can input. Ammending.

Comment: You might want to mention the birthday paradox: you only need to hash about 2^(N/2) values with an N-bit hash before you should expect a collision.

Comment: I guess I can. Seems like too much detail given the topic of the question, but why not.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hash values of 8 bits the total possible number of values is 256 - that means that if you hash 257 different n-grams there will be for sure at least one collision (...and very likely you will get many more collisions, even with less that 257 n-grams) - and this will happen regardless of the hashing algorithm or the data being hashed.

If you use 32 bits the total possible number of values is around 4 billion - and so the likelihood of a collision is much less.

'How does one choose the number of bits': I guess depends on the use of the hash. If it is used to store the n-grams in some kind of hashed data structure (a dictionary) then it should be related to the possible number of 'buckets' of the data structure - e.g. if the dictionary has less than 256 buckets that a 8 bit hash is OK.

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx) for some background